# WSO2 CEP configure database connection in file?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

Is there any way to configure an existing database connection via the file system and not inside the web application?

I am currently using a rdbms connection to an Oracle DB in order to store some events. I will be moving my implementation to a different system and thus I will have to change the database information (URL, username & password).

The database is not shown in the master-datasources XML-file. Is there a config file in which this information is stored? Or any other way without accessing the web console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a datasource in UI, that is saved in registry. `master-datasources.xml` is not updated with the new datasource. But you can configure your database in `master-datasources.xml`. Then once you restart the server it is also saved in registry, and you can use it just like a one you added in UI.

So basically what happens is that no matter how you add a datasource (either by xml or ui), they will be saved in registry, and you can use them afterwords in the same manner.